# Few campaigns not appearing in EXM dashboard

Tags: exm

Environment: Sitecore 9.0.2 and EXM

Issue: In the production environment, we have imported around 10 automated campaigns but only 4 are visible in the EXM dashboard under Email campaigns -> Automated.

I checked in the Content Editor and all 10 are present and 'Active' and 'Automated'.

The Email root is correct.

Few campaigns were 'Protected'. I have 'Unprotected' them but still they are not visible in the dashboard.

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: could you please confirm that you have added the node - /sitecore/content/Email Campaign to your Sitecore.ContentSearch.config or the custom patch file and indexing is done?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat: /sitecore/content itself is included in the list. The 4 e-mail campaigns visible are from the same root.

Comment: does reindex not help?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat: Another activity is going on in that environment. Once it is complete, I will re-index it and will let you know.

Comment: Is it possible that those campaigns were imported from another environment?

Comment: @Gatogordo: Yes, all the 10 campaigns were imported from a lower environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a campaign is not visible in EXM but it is shown in the content editor:

- go to the item in the content editor
- in the `Message Preview` tab, find the `Open EXM` button

[image]

- Click the button to open the message in EXM
- Go to the `Full email campaign` link on the right, to the `Delivery` step
- `Deactivate` the campaign and `activate` it again.

That should do the trick. It should be visible in your list now.

ps: this usually happens when importing messages.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Comment: Does this has any role in the statistics displayed on the dash-board? As I can see the e-mail ids and their actions in the lower section of the recipient activity tab but in the top half, the count is 0.

Comment: No idea.. this trick is to correctly link the email to the campaign (as that goes wrong when importing) - I'm not aware about any impact on analytics.

Comment: I did this for my 2 imported campaigns so they appear in EXM ok I think - but they are not selectable in my MA campaign for the send email action.  Have deactivated and reactivated.

Comment: @Jen Did you find any solution for this ? "not selectable in my MA campaign for the send email action"

Comment: @DebajitMukhopadhyay So I found that if I imported campaigns into a new environment.  If that environment didn't previously have that folder - I needed to move them into an existing folder on that environment then deactivate/reactivate them.  Potentially had to create a new exm campaign so that sitecore created the containing folder that I could move my imported items into.   If that doesn't make sense can provide screenshot.